# Are photons with a wavelength of the size of the universe possible - and what is their equation of state?

Tags: cosmology, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

Could the universe be filled with photons with a wavelength of the size of the universe? Do such photons exist?

If so, what would be their equation of state?

Comment: Have you tried to do a back-of-an-envelope-estimation?

Comment: For the equation of state of real photons, w=1/3. But this is only true if such real photons exist...

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that that equation of state holds for photons of some frequencies and not for others?

Comment: Yes. Claiming that a photon exists with a wavelength of the size of the universe is not self-evident. It is also questionable whether wavelengths larger than the size of the universe exist. They cannot be measured - so they look almost unscientific. That is the reason for the question.

Comment: You asked: *If they exist*, what would be their equation of state? Their possible nonexistence has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You are right. For real photons, w=1/3; for virtual photons, w=1. I could imagine that for photons with the wavelength of the universe, the two cases are hard to distinguish. Hence the question. Also, it is not clear that photons with the wavelength of the universe exist at all. And increasing the wavelength from smaller than the universe to as large as the universe, new aspects might come into play.